# Como meto uma descrição por baixo de uma imagem?

Tags: html

Boas, como meto uma descrição por baixo de uma imagem, dentro da div da imagem. Não posso usar em forma de tabela tem de ser mesmo dentro da div imagem

Comment: Você tem ai o código que está utilizando no momento?

Comment: Como assim? Já tentou inserir texto por baixo da imagem `<img src=....><p>Olá</p>`

Comment: Ok ja consegui colocar o texto por baixo da imagem mas agora queria mete-lo ao meio é essa parte que ainda não consegui

Answer (score 0):

[Veja esse link te ajuda:](http://www.dicasparablogs.com.br/2010/11/descricao-em-imagens-e-textos-tag-alt-e.html)

O atributo `alt` da tag img deve de atender: veja o exemplo do link acima:

```
<img src="endereço da imagem" alt="texto sobre a imagem" width="300" height="228" border="0" />
```